# How to change the subscription of an Observable in response to user action?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs

I am adding geolocation to my app, and I need to start the observable `Geolocation.watchPostion()` some time before the user actually requests the location.

I had the idea to create instance variables

```
private locationObserver = (stub observer);
private locationSubscription;
```

and do

```
this.locationSubscription = Geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(
  next => this.locationObserver.next(next),
  err  => this.locationObserver.error(error),
  comp => this.locationObserver.complete(complete)
)
```

And then at some later point call the following.

```
onRequestLocation(){
  this.locationObserver = Observer.create(
    location => {
      this.doMyStuff(location);
      this.locationSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  )
}
```

However, this doesn't feel like the right way to do this. Is this bad?

My goal is to start `Geolocation.watchPosition()`, and then, in response to a user event, start doing something. I would also like a timeout event to occur 5 seconds *after the user event*.

Here is another possibility that still doesn't feel right:

I make instance variables

```
private userEventHasOccured
private locationSubscription
```

and do

```
this.locationSubscription = Geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe(
  next => {
    if (userEventHasOccured) {
      this.doMyStuff(next);
      this.unsubscribeLocation();
    }
  }
)

public unsubscribeLocation() {
  this.locationSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

and

```
onUserEvent(){
  this.userEventHasOccured = true;
}
```

Also, is there a less annoying way of having a subscription end itself?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a lack of understanding. Of course an observable can have more than one subscription.

Edit: Sorry! Some more explanation.

In the end, my working solution was to declare instance variables

```
this.stubSubscription
this.actualSubscription
```

and then call the following on page load, user action, and page leave, respectively.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.stubSubscription = Geolocation.watchPosition()
    .subscribe(() => {}, () => {});

onUserAction() {
  this.actualSubscription = Geolocation.watchPosition()
    .first(position => position.coords.accuracy <= 50) // 1st accurate-enough result
    .subscribe(position => this.doMyStuff(position))

ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.stubSubscription.unsubscribe();
  this.actualSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

ionic appears to be very good about actually calling `willeave`whenever the user leaves. if not called, then geolocation just keeps running until the app is closed, which is bad. I would like to do this in a more reactive, as opposed to imperative, way...

Edit 2: I'm sure this is still not the best way to do this -- if you have any suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Please either elaborate with the working solution (code). This current answer doesn't really provide enough information. Thanks! :)

Comment: Of course. My solution ended up being to create _two_ subscriptions on the same observable -- one to "start" it, and one in response to user input -- then unsubscribing them both to "stop" the observable.

Comment: Looks better! You get a +1 for that ;)